# Limit array, angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Trying to limit the output from an array. list is the array in the data object.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data.list" ng-if=""><td>{{item.data.attribute}}</td></tr>
```

Is it possible to do with ng-repeat?

Comment: if you want to use in ng-if you can use $index..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing remove `ng-if`. Then use `limitTo` filter provided by angular out of the box.

```
ng-repeat="item in data.list | limitTo: 4 as filtered"
```

You could use the same filter inside controller as well.

```
var limit = 5;
$scope.filteredData = $filter('limitTo')($scope.data.list)(limit);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, that the best way is to use `limitTo`

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data.list |limitTo:quantity"><td>{{item.data.attribute}}</td></tr>
```

where `quantity` is your limit. Also you can use:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data.list" ng-if="$index < quantity"><td>{{item.data.attribute}}</td></tr>
```

But it's not the best solution as this would be less efficient than using limitToFilter if it's a large array, because every item presumably has to be evaluated, one more thing `ng-if`, in this case, will not render the `DOM element` of the repeater whose `$index` is greater than `quantity`. if `$index` in the repeater is `0, 1, or 2 or`quantity, the condition is true and the DOM nodes are created. `ng-if` differs from `ng-hide` in the sense that elements are not added to the DOM

One more thing, you ca add filter to your controller

```
.filter('limitItems', function () {/*CODE OF YOUR FILTER FUNCTION*/})
```